# How to add a Facebook "share" button to a "quick view" pop-up modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, modal-dialog

How can I add a Facebook "share" button to a "quick view" pop-up modal? In other words, **if somebody wanted to share a product on my site, through the "quick view" modal, how do I have the Facebook "share" button share that products link, since the modal pops up in "/products"?**

If you have a look at what I'm talking about and click the "QUICK LOOK" button when you hover over a product:

http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/products

Currently, I have a "like" button, and that isn't what I want, I just want to swap it for a "share" button and have the "share" button on the modal link to the right page properly.

This is what Facebook's share button's Javascript SDK looks like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And here's the standard code for the plugin:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"    data-type="button"></div>
```

***EDIT****

**Here's the current code I'm using for the "like" button:**

```
 <li id="social_facebook">
 <div class="social_action">
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com{{ product.url }}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width: 80px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you include the code you use to display the like button? We know how to include the FB JS SDK from their docs - what we don't know are any of the variables your site uses to generate the like buttons and therefore it would be very difficult for us to show you how to turn the like buttons into share buttons.

Comment: Edited it! Look to post for "like" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try assembling all the pieces to this bit of code which you can use to replace the code you included for the like button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<li id="social_facebook">
   <div class="social_action">
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com{{ product.url }}" data-type="button"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I pasted that in and now the button isn't showing up. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It appears on your page for me - but I think you might need to fiddle with the CSS to align the buttons a bit. Screenshot from my machine - http://imgur.com/jeIazm1

Comment: Works now, actually. Just tested again! Doesn't work on FF though.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work so well in FireFox - the first time I open the Quick look overlay, it doesn't show - if I then close it and open again, it works

Comment: You're right. Does that for me too. Anything we can do? Haha. That's strange.

Comment: maybe try adding some extra javascript: `FB.XFBML.parse();` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222720/facebook-like-and-share-button-on-ajax

Comment: Added that and it's still doing the same thing

Comment: I had the button as an iframe before. Should we try doing that with the new script you gave me to have it work properly, instead?

Comment: Yes, try adding as an iframe - remember to use `http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com{{ product.url }}` as the link you want to share

Comment: Is it possible to add an iframe for share buttons? Haha. It's not saying there's an option. Shoot.

Comment: I think if you add the Firefox issue as a new question, someone else should be able to help you.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help though! At least the button is sharing the right page now :)